# Datetime.utc returns 1-1-0001 00:00:00 in event viewer

Tags: c#, datetime

I wanted to return the current date to my event logger, I've tried this:

```
public class LogDate
{
    protected DateTime localDate { get; set; }

    public LogDate()
    {
        localDate = DateTime.Now;

    }
}
```

.

```
public class Eventlog : LogDate
{
    public void logEvent(string answer)
    {

       this.localDate = new DateTime();


        try
        {
            string sSource;
            string sLog;
            string sEvent;

            sSource = "dotNET Sample App";
            sLog = "filmdatabase";
            sEvent = this.localDate + answer;
```

Somehow when I try this, it returns 1-1-0001 00:00:00. Instead of the actual time.

Comment: By the way, there is no `DateTime.UtcNow` in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify `this.localDate` to a new `DateTime` again:

```
this.localDate = new DateTime();
```

`1-1-0001 00:00:00` is the default value for `new DateTime()`. To fix it, use `this.localDate` without re-assigning it with `new DateTime()`.

```
public class Eventlog : LogDate
{
    public void logEvent(string answer)
    {

       //this.localDate = new DateTime(); //remove this    

        try
        {
            string sSource;
            string sLog;
            string sEvent;

            sSource = "dotNET Sample App";
            sLog = "filmdatabase";
            sEvent = this.localDate.ToString() + " " + answer; //use it directly as you have initialized that in your constructor
```

Use it directly as you have always initialized it in your constructor:

```
public class LogDate
{
    protected DateTime localDate { get; set; }

    public LogDate()
    {
        localDate = DateTime.Now;

    }
}
```

Comment: @LarsKroeze that OK... :)

Answer (score 1):

You set `localDate` to new default value

```
this.localDate = new DateTime();
```